# what's wrong in my php code?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my database,my table name is users,now I want to update password when my name and contact is true.When I execute this code print error in my browser,but my name and contact is true and exist in my table.what is my problem in this code?

```
    <?php

 $hostname_localhost ="localhost";
    $database_localhost ="db_project";
    $username_localhost ="root";
    $password_localhost ="123456";
    $localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
    or
    trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

    mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

/*$u_name=$_POST["name"];
$u_pass=$_POST["password"];
$u_contact=$_POST["contact"];*/

$u_name="hamid";
$u_contact="123456";
$u_password="3333333";


    $sql_query="UPDATE users SET 'password'='".$u_password."' where name='".$u_name."' AND contact='".$u_contact."'";
    if(mysql_query($sql_query))
    echo "ok";
    else
    echo "error";

?>
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: I personally think your server is telling you *"Don't use `mysql_*`, and certainly don't do this: `"UPDATE users SET 'password'='".$u_password."' where name='".$u_name."' AND contact='".$u_contact."'"`"*

Comment: a) don't use `mysql`, it's been deprecated and in PHP7 removed. use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. b) use parameterised queries whenever possible. c) it seems you store passwords as plain text - don't do that. use `password_hash` to create a hash and `password_verify` to check it.

Comment: First of all use mysqli or PDO as mysql is depricated. To the question please print your query and run direct on server it's working or not.

Comment: @weigreen read my code,,,i said in this code when the query is true print ok,,,when can not exec query print error

Comment: Downvoted because you didn't bother replying to multiple questions asking **what is your error**.

Comment: did you please send me error data.or url

Comment: Please print this and check which kind of query are you send to server. $sql_query="UPDATE users SET 'password'='".$u_password."' where name='".$u_name."' AND contact='".$u_contact."'";

Answer (score 0):

I think there is ' with your column name. You need to change that to `: Pls try below

```
$sql_query="UPDATE users SET `password`='".$u_password."' where name='".$u_name."' AND contact='".$u_contact."'";
```

Comment: now update my table,,,but when i entry a false data,print ok again :-\

Comment: I didn't downvote you but it's probably because the OP shouldn't be doing this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the SQL query as below:

```
$sql_query="UPDATE users SET password='".$u_password."' 
            WHERE name='".$u_name."' AND contact='".$u_contact."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step : 1** Print a query and **check an output using PHPMyadmin** or whatever you are using as DB server.Here you will get a right output.

**Step : 2**  If you have get appropriate result then you have to move and use same query as `$mysql_query` and output of you query using,
`$result = mysql_query($sql_query) or die("MySQL error:".mysql_error());`

$result will never be false : either mysql_query returns true, or the script dies.

**Step : 3**If you rather want to check if your UPDATE query had any effect at all, you can use this:
Use `mysql_affected_rows()`